# powrshell command does not run when I run the entire script

Tags: windows, powershell, symantec

I wrote a ps1 script to automate some package installation but the strange part is when I run the command snippet for executing the .exe file for SEP (Symantec Endpoint Protection) , it is executing fine , but when I execute the entire script , it does run the command snippet.
Iam only running a simple .exe file , and even if I run it manually , it does not show any installer , rather it installs silently in the background.
So in the script, Iam only running the .exe file, thats it .
Should I be giving any wait time or any other inputs ?

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Temp\Symantec-Windows\SEP 14.3.3384.1000 x64.exe" -passthru
$SymVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $hostname | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -eq "symantec endpoint protection"} | Format-List -Property version, InstallState, name
echo $SymVersion
if($SymVersion)
{
echo 'Symantec is successfully installed' -ForegroundColor Green 
}
else
{
echo 'Symantec is not successfully installed' -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Avoid querying Win32_Product - see here: https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/

Comment: Perhaps looking in the various [logs](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/154595/required-logs-for-troubleshooting-failed.html) can help you out?

Comment: How do I save the installation logs ? @theo

Comment: The SEP installer creates those logs, so after running the installation .exe, look in those to see if [1] they can be found at all [2] you can spot errors in them. I don't have examples of the logs available unfortunately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symantec antivirus exe files are made for silent installations. If you want to proceed with GUI mode, better unzip the file and use MSI file with arguments. With your current script,Its better to check the process is exited with code 0. The following code is not tested.

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\Symantec-Windows\SEP 14.3.3384.1000 x64.exe" -passthru -Wait
if($process.ExitCode -ne 0)
{
    throw "Installation process returned error code: $($process.ExitCode)"
} else { Write-Host "Installation Successful"}
```

Comment: tried with this method , but the same issue was coming , the .exe file was not getting executed at all

Comment: It's better to look for the installation log file. Installation failure can happen for various reasons, please refer the following link: https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/152795/where-can-i-find-endpoint-protection-cli.html